# Is it physically or algorithmically possible to implement continuous observation of parameter changes in a quantum gate?

Tags: quantum-gate

Since direct observation of qubits collapses the quantum state and prevents the original state from being obtained, does continuously monitoring the parameters of a quantum gate collapse the quantum state? How is it possible to continuously monitor the parameters of a quantum gate without directly observing the quantum state?

For example, let us assume that there is a VQE(such as hardware-efficient ansatz) which consists of various parametric quantum gates. This is because the measurement of bits leads to quantum state collapse. Therefore, we would like to switch to measuring the parameters of the quantum gates. Are there physical methods or computer algorithms that address the above needs?

To be more specific, suppose the VQE consists of 5 CRY(theta), and its goal is to perform some classification task. I don't want to do this by reading qubits, but by reading the parameters that change in the quantum gates.

Comment: What do you mean by continuously? The circuit/gate is a discrete entity. You apply the gate integer number of times.

Comment: Are you referring to what's happenning in Variational Algorithms such as VQE?

Comment: How the parameter changes in the VQC are implemented, that is, the process of iterative changes in the quantum gate parameters in real time, hence the need to read out the parameters in them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "VQC", and what you mean by "measuring the parameters of the quantum gates"? As @EvgeniyZh comments, implementing a parameterized gate is an inherently discrete operation. To apply $U(\theta)$ and then $U(\theta+\delta\theta)$ is to apply two distinct gates, and that is typically what we think about in variational quantum algorithms. But maybe you are thinking about continuously applying $U(\delta\theta)$ repeatedly, and "counting" the number of times you have to apply it before the quantum state has some property?